# I am trying to bind a text area to an angularjs variable and have it reflect changes I make to the text area with jquery, in the angular js variable

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to bind a text box to an angularjs variable and have it output rendered html in a separate div.  I also want to manage the data in that div with jquery.  When I update using jquery the bound angularjs does not update.

I have:

```
$('#sections, #phases').change(
...
$('textarea#displayData').val(html);
```

This works.  When sections or phases change, displayData gets updated.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<form:textarea ng-model="ddata" id="displayData" path="displayData"/>

<div ng-bind-html-unsafe='ddata'>
{{ddata}}
</div></div>
```

This also works.  When I modify displayData in the text area, the bound ddata variable shows my change.

What doesn't happen is when the sections or phases change, and the displayData gets updated, the ddata doesn't reflect that change.

Comment: Mixing jQuery with Angular in the way you seem to be doing is going to give you trouble. You don't need to do it the hard way anymore, and I'm willing to bet Angular has a simpler way, but it's hard to give more advice without seeing what you're trying to accomplish in the jQuery functions.

Comment: I'm using jquery to pull json off a rest service and populating form elements (dropdowns).  I'm guessing angular can do that but the jquery portion was already written and I had everything going but the return bind to ddata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the *angular world* to know about changes made *outside the angular world*, you must do the changes using [scope.$apply()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)

```
//jQuery world
$(function() {
    var scope = angular.element("textarea#displayData").scope();
    scope.$apply(function(){
        // angular world
        scope.ddata = html;
    });
});
```

See a working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YnXZQm78M9nMqd9uOURz?p=preview