# How to make a model 'dirty' in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a markdown editor.

```
<textarea class="wnd-content-textarea" 
          name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" 
          ng-model="content"
          ng-change="">
</textarea>
```

I use a jquery plugin to update the a model that is binded on textarea element:

```
scope.execEditorCmd = function (cmd) {
  // List of commands:
  // 'cmd-bold', 
  // 'cmd-italic',
  // 'cmd-quote',
  // 'cmd-unorder-list',
  // 'cmd-order-list'

  /**
  * Get selected text in textarea tag. 
  * textrange() is dependent on jquery-textrange plugin
  * @type {Object}
  * e.g.: {position: 4, start: 4, end: 8, length: 4, text: "reqw"}
  */
  var selectedTextObj = $textAreaElement.textrange('get');
  // Execute the string replace command using structure defined before
  var boldedText = selectedTextObj.text
    .replace( markdownCmd[cmd].search , markdownCmd[cmd].replace);

  // Actually replace the orginal text with executed string in textarea.
  // $timeout();

  $textAreaElement.textrange('replace', boldedText);

  // Not sure if it is the right way, but I have to do it to update model. 
  scope.content = $textAreaElement.val();
};
```

The jquery plguin is [here](https://github.com/dwieeb/jquery-textrange):

The text on in the textarea changed in browser, but the model actually still remains the same. I checked it by `{{}}` outputing in in browser and log it in console.

At this moment, if I type a space in textarea, then all the changes that this plugin had done will reflected in model.

I tried scope.$apply, which result in console error. 
I also tried `$timeout(function(/* jquery updating */){})`, nothing changes.

How do I make the change reflected on model? 
- trigger it dirty? 
- any best practice?

Thank you!

Comment: can you show us more code?

Comment: This has already been answered elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815177/i-am-trying-to-bind-a-text-area-to-an-angularjs-variable-and-have-it-reflect-cha

Comment: Reproduce the error in stacksnippet

Comment: mwarren, thanks for letting me know that it is already been answered.